# The JPA LOCK TABLE statement causes an exception for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jpa

In order to prevent concurrent updates to a table by different threads, we protect it with

`em.createNativeQuery("LOCK TABLE mytable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE").executeUpdate();`

where `em` is a JPA EntityManager.
This is working correctly in Postgres but not in SQL Server (and I think in Oracle it may not be working either).
Is there something to enable in SQL Server so that the above JPA statement does not give a " SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001,  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'" error?

Comment: If you are writing your own query, see [Hints (Transact-SQL) - Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: As @Larnu said you have to provide that in the SELECT statement. There is no LOCK TABLE command in SQL Server

Comment: Firstly, there is no such command for SQL Server. Secondly, although there are ways to do this, you probably don't need it. Why do you think you need to lock the whole table?

Comment: An aggregated object is written from several objects of a given type. So to ensure the aggregated object contains all the objects added by different threads, a lock on the whole table is an easy solution.

Comment: Well no, the best way of doing this is to get all the objects into a list, and batch it up as a Table Valued Parameter or as JSON/XML, and insert the whole thing in one go. Locking the whole table is complete overkill

Comment: The whole thing is a bit more complex than I can explain, there is more than one table and business object involved. Also the table lock is used as a synchronization-across-Kubernetes-pods mechanism. Rather than using a monitor, which would only provide synchronization in a Java VM, the table lock is used as a synchronization mechanism when there is more than one pod of the same "type".

Comment: Locking the table is still expensive - could the transactions not just lock a well known single row/entity for the purpose? Then you could let JPA issue the statement via em.find(LockingEntity.class, wellKnownId,  LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); and let JPA worry about the database locking semantics

Comment: Yes, this is what I have ended up doing, from some of the previous comments and asking my workmates. Your comment might be the accepted answer if you wrote it as an answer.